# How to remove leading and trailing double-quotes coming from local storage using angular or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is got to be simple so here's the deal;

I place the following ARRAY of objects (JSON) into local storage and it appears like this:

```
[{"id": 150, "label": "Animal Cookies (Phat Panda)"}, {"id": 110, "label": "Blue Dream (Pioneer)"}, {"id": 30, "label": "Candyland"}, {"id": 130, "label": "Dragon OG (Avitas)"}, {"id": 20, "label": "Golden Pineapple Family"}, {"id": 140, "label": "Golden Ticket (Liberty Reach)"}, {"id": 120, "label": "GSC: Thin Mint (Phat Panda)"}, {"id": 40, "label": "Jack Herer Master Blend"}, {"id": 80, "label": "Owyn's White Widow Blend Master"}, {"id": 50, "label": "P91 San Diego Family"}, {"id": 60, "label": "Phat Panda"}, {"id": 100, "label": "Space Queen Family Sativa"}, {"id": 10, "label": "Trash"}, {"id": 70, "label": "Urkel"}, {"id": 90, "label": "White Widow"}]
```

Yes, these are Cannabis strains and I'm building a software for Cannabis growers.

PROBLEM:

When I retrieve it like so:

```
           /**
             * Angular Dropdown Multi-select
             * http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main - <<<< EXAMPLE HERE!
             * For STRAINS to select what will be in the room selected
             *
             */
            $scope.plantWizModel = [];
            $scope.plantWizData = [];
            //Get the REFORMATTED data from LOCALSTORAGE
            //$scope.plantWizData = storageLocalService.getItemJSON("strainsmini");

            $scope.plantWizData = [{"id": 150, "label": "Animal Cookies (Phat Panda)"}, {"id": 110, "label": "Blue Dream (Pioneer)"}, {"id": 30, "label": "Candyland"}, {"id": 130, "label": "Dragon OG (Avitas)"}, {"id": 20, "label": "Golden Pineapple Family"}, {"id": 140, "label": "Golden Ticket (Liberty Reach)"}, {"id": 120, "label": "GSC: Thin Mint (Phat Panda)"}, {"id": 40, "label": "Jack Herer Master Blend"}, {"id": 80, "label": "Owyn's White Widow Blend Master"}, {"id": 50, "label": "P91 San Diego Family"}, {"id": 60, "label": "Phat Panda"}, {"id": 100, "label": "Space Queen Family Sativa"}, {"id": 10, "label": "Trash"}, {"id": 70, "label": "Urkel"}, {"id": 90, "label": "White Widow"}];
            console.log("PLANT WIZ DATA: ", $scope.plantWizData);
            $scope.plantWizSettings = {
                checkBoxes: true
            };
            $scope.plantWizCustomTexts = {
                buttonDefaultText: 'Select up to 4 Strains',
                selectionLimit: 4
            };
```

> What I get is THIS: PERFECTION...

[image]

> BUT, when I change the code from "HARD CODING" the $scope.plantWizData
>   like so:

```
$scope.plantWizData = storageLocalService.getItemJSON("strainsmini");
```

> The error I get is this:

```
angular.js:12332 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not 
allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: option 
in options, Duplicate key: string:", Duplicate value: "
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=option%20in%20options&p1=string%3A%22&p2=%22
    at angular.js:68
    at ngRepeatAction (angular.js:27144)
    at Object.$watchCollectionAction [as fn] (angular.js:15550)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15685)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15953)
    at done (angular.js:10366)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10538)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10479)
```

> Therefore, this is the result:

[image]

> What's apparently occuring is that when I get the data from LOCAL
>   STORAGE, "" appear LEADING and TRAILING on $scope.plantWizData = [];
>   like so:

```
$scope.plantWizData = >>>> "[{"id": 150, "label": "Animal Cookies (Phat Panda)"}, {"id": 110, "label": "Blue Dream (Pioneer)"}, {"id": 30, "label": "Candyland"}, {"id": 130, "label": "Dragon OG (Avitas)"}, {"id": 20, "label": "Golden Pineapple Family"}, {"id": 140, "label": "Golden Ticket (Liberty Reach)"}, {"id": 120, "label": "GSC: Thin Mint (Phat Panda)"}, {"id": 40, "label": "Jack Herer Master Blend"}, {"id": 80, "label": "Owyn's White Widow Blend Master"}, {"id": 50, "label": "P91 San Diego Family"}, {"id": 60, "label": "Phat Panda"}, {"id": 100, "label": "Space Queen Family Sativa"}, {"id": 10, "label": "Trash"}, {"id": 70, "label": "Urkel"}, {"id": 90, "label": "White Widow"}]" <<<<;
```

> So, how do I get rid of them because I need to keep this solution
>   DYNAMIC and not STATIC?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is use of angularjs necessary?

Comment: Probably because you haven't parsed the json in `storageLocalService.getItemJSON`. Show that code

Comment: Can also save yourself setting and getting by using `ngStorage` module

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use template literal to create valid `JSON` without leading or trailing double quotation marks

```
let json = `[{"id": 150, ..}]`;
localStorage.setItem("json", json);
let o = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("json"));
```

Comment: GUEST271314 - I selected YOUR ANSWER because all I had to do was simply add JSON.parse() surrounding my pull from local storage and IT WORKED the first time. THANK YOU for the simplest and most correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `JSON.parse` removes double quotes.